# How to use nvidia-docker without sudoing before each docker command

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I installed nvidia-docker on Ubuntu 22.04 in order to use my GPU in my containers.

It works when I use the command `sudo docker run --gpus all test/image:latest nvidia-smi`, but if I try without sudo, I get this:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Unknown runtime specified nvidia.
```

I can't use sudo in all environments, so this won't do. Plus now `docker ps` and `docker image ls` only show containers and images created without sudo, to display the other dockers I have to do `sudo docker ps` and so on for all docker commands.

Moreover docker-desktop completely ignores any container launched with a `sudo` command, which makes it useless.

Comment: can u list out some details on how u installed. Going through the documentation `22.04` is not supported

Comment: I followed the official instructions on [this page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/). 22.04 is supported, it is listed under "OS requirements". Edit: oh you meant the nvidia runtime. You're right I didn't realize 22.04 was not supported. I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html) with no issues.

Comment: Usually you just need to add the user to the docker group in order to run without sudo. But I assume you've have already done that.